# How to scroll to a line number in JSON within div panel?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following snippet as part of an AngularJS Web App to display a JSON within a tabbed panel.

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="version-tabs">
        <tabset>
            <tab ng-repeat="data in dataDict.versions" heading="{{data}}"
                 active="dataDict.versionSelection[data].active">
                <div class="pad-top-sm">
                    <pre class="response-textarea-tab pad-top-sm">{{formatJson(dataDict.versionSelection[data].json) | json}}</pre>
                </div>
            </tab>
        </tabset>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I'd like to scroll to a line number within the JSON when the user selects a json path i.e. I'd like to show the line number leading to a difference to show some context to the user.

How can I do that using Javacript/AngularJS?

PS: I still need to figure out how to calculate the line number given the JSON path specially when the JSON is formatted but I will find a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way - it's generate each line with unique identified (your line number) that will be used in url hash to navigate: `<div id="line5">Line 5 content</div>`. So you can use `a` anchor element with `href` as id of your line identifier: `<a href="#line5">Navigate to line 5</a>`.

Check fiddle below

```css
div { 
  padding-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="version-tabs">
        <tabset>
            <a href="#line5">Navigate to line 5</a>
            <tab ng-repeat="data in dataDict.versions" heading="{{data}}"
                 active="dataDict.versionSelection[data].active">
                <div class="pad-top-sm">
                    <pre class="response-textarea-tab pad-top-sm">                                 <div id="line1">Line 1</div>
                      <div id="line2">Line 2</div>
                      <div id="line3">Line 3</div>
                      <div id="line4">Line 4</div>
                      <div id="line5">Line 5</div>
                      <div id="line6">Line 6</div>
                      <div id="line7">Line 7</div>
                      <div id="line8">Line 8</div>
                      <div id="line9">Line 9</div>
                      <div id="line10">Line 10</div>                    </pre>
                </div>
            </tab>
        </tabset>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This has the added benefit of the URL being shareable: `http://example.com/path#line42`